# New SE site for vegetarianism and veganism

Tags: discussion

There's an Area 51 site for Veganism & Vegetarianism. I figured there would be a fair amount of vegetarians and vegans here, so I thought I'd post it here for those who may be interested! It's currently in the commit phase, so if you feel you can contribute or want to learn something, please practice Mettā by coming along and committing!

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Veganism & Vegetarianism]